# Why is ListPlot so slow here?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, system-performance, backslide

While examining [How can I monitor the progress of a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84416/121) I was surprised to discover that in some cases [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) in version 10.0 and 10.1 is orders of magnitude slower than it is in version 7.  This is *not* rendering time but generation of the `Graphics` itself.  Here is an example.

```
dat = Table[{x, y}, {x, 200}, {y, RandomReal[9, 500]}];

lp = ListPlot[dat, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

*Rendering* this plot takes only ~0.08 second according to [`EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32030/121) as seen by evaluating `lp` separately.  However *generating* `lp` (in 10.1) is quite slow:

```
ListPlot[dat] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 2.02
> ```

This takes only 0.018 second in version 7.  Why is 10.1 two orders of magnitude slower?

---

[David Skulsky](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27/david-skulsky) reports these `AbsoluteTiming` results:

> MacBook Air: v8 2.1 sec, v9 0.43 sec, v10 3.6 sec.

Apparently the problem is not limited to v10 though it is most severe there.  Should this not be a simple operation and much faster than this as indeed it was in version 7?

---

### First attempt at analysis

Since no useful explanation had yet been provided I thought I would see if I could learn anything with a [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).  What I learned is that the sheer size of `Trace` is comically, exasperatingly large:

```
bigTrace = Trace[ListPlot[dat]];

ByteCount[bigTrace]
```

> ```
> 5728324392
> ```

A five and a half *gigabyte* trace?  *Really?*  I'll keep trying to learn more but that's just depressing.  Can this be considered a bug?  Someone please tell me this has been fixed after version 10.1.

Comment: Has anyone looked more broadly at plotting speeds?  Apparently StreamPlot is slower too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78938/streamplot-slow-in-version-10?rq=1

Comment: @David I have not but I hope that someone does; it would be interesting. Unlike the case of `StreamPlot` there should be no addaptive sampling in `ListPlot`; it should be a rather direct conversion to `Point` expressions with styling added.  It should *not* be this slow.

Comment: @David Did you confirm that v9 is not affected by this?  I did not add a version tag because I do not have access to v8 and v9 to check.

Comment: I get ~0.5 seconds with v9/windows and ~6 seconds 10.1/linux

Comment: Intel is partnering with WR

Comment: @belisarius I fear I am missing out on your clever humor; is Intel also getting slower?  (Sorry to have to ask for an explanation and spoil the joke.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nope. Intel machines are going faster. That's why you want to buy them their new processor to be able to run your old code

Comment: @belisarius Oh, *that*.  :-D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I don't have v7 any longer, but here are my numbers on my pokey MacBook Air: v8 2.1 sec, v9 0.43 sec, v10 3.6 sec.  I used lp=ListPlot[dat];//AbsoluteTiming since it appears RepeatedTiming wasn't available until v10 (?).  Anyway, it looks like you're correct--this may not be v10-specific.

Comment: @David Thanks for the timings.  I'll update the tags/title accordingly.

Comment: For reference creating essentially the exact same plot with `Graphics/Point` takes 0.0005 seconds (both versions..).

Comment: In version 10.1, I get a reduction in the timing by a factor of 2 simply by adding `Joined->True` to `ListPlot`. In version 8, the same change reduces the timing almost ten-fold! Apparently, it's harder to make points than to draw lines. Who would have thought... Same thing happens when I use `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot`.

Comment: It's no better in 10.3.1. I tried this but it wasn't as informative as I'd hoped: ``Module[{a = AbsoluteTime[]}, Block[{Charting`dbPrint = Print[AbsoluteTime[] - a, " ", #] &}, ListPlot[dat]]]``

Comment: I wondered about injecting timing information into the Trace to help locate the problem area in the huge output, but Trace adds its own delays.

Comment: The large size of the trace comes from hundreds of copies of the data: `ByteCount[nodat = bigTrace /. Dispatch@Join[{dat -> "DAT", N@dat -> "NDAT"}, Thread[dat -> Table["DAT[[" <> ToString[i] <> "]]", {i, Length@dat}]], Thread[N@dat -> Table["NDAT[[" <> ToString[i] <> "]]", {i, Length@dat}]], {Flatten[N@dat, 1] -> "FlatNDAT"}]]` -> 600MB, about three times the size on V9 with the same trick. I get a 40% (time) savings with ``ndat = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@dat; ListPlot[ndat] // AbsoluteTiming``, fwiw, in V10.3.1.  Still not easy to examine.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for looking at it.  I contend that if there are hundreds of copies of the data that itself indicates a problem; this should not be an operation that takes hundreds of steps to prepare.  This degree of bloat is simply unacceptable IMO, and it greatly diminishes the touted usefulness of `Manipulate` type functionality.

Comment: Yes, it seems quite a backslide.  It may be because of units and `Quantity` and other such fancy plot-handling embellishments that the data seems to be processed so many times (550 times in V10, 400 in V9). The same graphics can be produced with `Graphics` in `0.01` sec. by comparison -- It also was computing the data ranges of the sublists in `dat`, but I find it hard to believe that takes a long time.  There was too much to go through to narrow down just what was taking so long; maybe it is just all of it together.

Comment: Still present in 11.0.0 - I get a 6.2 GB trace from `ByteCount[Trace[ListPlot[dat]]]`! Takes about 2.4 sec on my PC.

Comment: @blochwave Oh no it's getting worse! :-O

Comment: @Mr.Wizard plus I see the same on Linux and Windows!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how accurate this is, but it's a start for analysis at least.

I wrote a timed trace function:

```
TimedTrace[code_] :=
  With[{data =
     Reap[
       Quiet@TraceScan[
         Sow[AbsoluteTime[] -> #] &, code, ___, 
         Sow[AbsoluteTime[]] &]
       ][[2, 1]]},
   Block[{stack = {}, step = 1, results = <||>},
    Table[
     If[Length@cur != 2,
      results[First@Last@stack] =
       Abs[(cur - First@Last@Last@stack)] -> Last@Last@Last@stack;
      stack = Delete[stack, -1],
      AppendTo[stack, {step, cur}]
      ]; step++,
     {cur, data}
     ];
    KeySort@results
    ]
   ];
TimedTrace~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

which was nowhere near fast enough to analyze the call proper, so I made a tiny version of the data:

```
dat2 = Table[{x, y}, {x, 2}, {y, RandomReal[9, 5]}];
```

which takes about .025 seconds to run.

Ran a trace:

```
trData = TimedTrace[ListPlot[dat2, ImageSize -> 600]];
```

Took a few seconds to run (owing to all the `Sow` calls I think). Thing is huge:

```
In[315]:= trData // Length

Out[315]= 90435
```

Tried to find calls that took a while:

```
0.111324->(System`ProtoPlotDump`theme$19304=Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[System`ProtoPlotDump`plottheme$19304,ListPlot])
0.111292->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[System`ProtoPlotDump`plottheme$19304,ListPlot]
0.111257->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.111248->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,SymbolName[ListPlot]]
0.111199->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.111189->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[SymbolName[Automatic],ListPlot]
0.111141->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.111130->Themes`makeThemeMethodOption[Themes`SortRulesAndExtract[Join[System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot],Themes`DefaultStyles[ListPlot]]],ListPlot]
0.101492->(System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19304=Charting`customStyle[System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19304,System`ProtoPlotDump`defaultstyle$19304,System`ProtoPlotDump`length$19304,BaseStyle->System`ProtoPlotDump`basestyle$19304])
0.101461->Charting`customStyle[System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19304,System`ProtoPlotDump`defaultstyle$19304,System`ProtoPlotDump`length$19304,BaseStyle->System`ProtoPlotDump`basestyle$19304]
0.101327->Charting`customStyle[Automatic,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378691127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378694657*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378699184*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378703964*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378708102*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378711855*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378715402*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378718887*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378722316*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378725677*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378729106*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378732568*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378737444*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378742241*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378746251*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]},2,BaseStyle->{}]
0.101309->Module[{Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$},{Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$}=OptionValue[{BaseStyle->{}},{BaseStyle}];Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378691127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378694657*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378699184*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378703964*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378708102*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378711855*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378715402*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378718887*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378722316*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378725677*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378729106*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378732568*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378737444*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378742241*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378746251*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic]]
0.101276->({Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19370}=OptionValue[{BaseStyle->{}},{BaseStyle}];Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19370,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378691127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378694657*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378699184*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378703964*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378708102*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378711855*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378715402*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378718887*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378722316*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378725677*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378729106*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378732568*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378737444*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378742241*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378746251*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic])
0.101163->Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19370,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378691127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378694657*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378699184*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378703964*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378708102*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378711855*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378715402*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378718887*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378722316*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378725677*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378729106*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378732568*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378737444*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378742241*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587378746251*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic]
0.123557->(System`ProtoPlotDump`theme$19380=Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[System`ProtoPlotDump`plottheme$19380,ListPlot])
0.123497->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[System`ProtoPlotDump`plottheme$19380,ListPlot]
0.123456->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.123441->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,SymbolName[ListPlot]]
0.123386->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.123372->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[SymbolName[Automatic],ListPlot]
0.123318->Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot]
0.123302->Themes`makeThemeMethodOption[Themes`SortRulesAndExtract[Join[System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[Automatic,ListPlot],Themes`DefaultStyles[ListPlot]]],ListPlot]
0.103445->(System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19380=Charting`customStyle[System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19380,System`ProtoPlotDump`defaultstyle$19380,System`ProtoPlotDump`length$19380,BaseStyle->System`ProtoPlotDump`basestyle$19380])
0.103403->Charting`customStyle[System`ProtoPlotDump`plotstyle$19380,System`ProtoPlotDump`defaultstyle$19380,System`ProtoPlotDump`length$19380,BaseStyle->System`ProtoPlotDump`basestyle$19380]
0.103242->Charting`customStyle[Automatic,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379138477*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379141967*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379145435*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379149015*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379152376*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379155806*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379160336*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379165260*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379169506*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379173127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379176497*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379180044*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379183421*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379186882*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379190351*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]},2,BaseStyle->{}]
0.103222->Module[{Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$},{Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$}=OptionValue[{BaseStyle->{}},{BaseStyle}];Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379138477*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379141967*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379145435*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379149015*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379152376*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379155806*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379160336*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379165260*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379169506*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379173127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379176497*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379180044*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379183421*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379186882*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379190351*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic]]
0.103180->({Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19448}=OptionValue[{BaseStyle->{}},{BaseStyle}];Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19448,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379138477*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379141967*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379145435*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379149015*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379152376*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379155806*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379160336*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379165260*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379169506*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379173127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379176497*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379180044*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379183421*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379186882*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379190351*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic])
0.103049->Charting`getPlotStyles[Charting`CommonDump`baseStyleSolver[Charting`CommonDump`basestyle$19448,{Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379138477*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379141967*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379145435*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379149015*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379152376*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379155806*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379160336*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379165260*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379169506*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379173127*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379176497*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379180044*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379183421*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379186882*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]],Directive[,AbsoluteThickness[1.6],3.690587379190351*10^9->(Sow[#1,Charting`CommonDump`head[#1]]&)/@Reverse[Charting`CommonDump`new]]}]][2,Automatic]
```

Obviously all those timings are off as there's no way these took that long. They're probably capturing other stuff, given the shoddy way I wrote the tracer, so let's recalculate the timings for them:

```
0.111324->0.004826
0.111292->0.00417
0.111257->0.003695
0.111248->0.003625
0.111199->0.00341
0.111189->0.003539
0.111141->0.003517
0.111130->0.003444
0.101492->0.000976
0.101461->0.000876
0.101327->0.000755
0.101309->0.00073
0.101276->0.00075
0.101163->0.000722
0.123557->0.003747
0.123497->0.00333
0.123456->0.003595
0.123441->0.003322
0.123386->0.003348
0.123372->0.003558
0.123318->0.0033
0.123302->0.003568
0.103445->0.001011
0.103403->0.000882
0.103242->0.000744
0.103222->0.00074
0.103180->0.000725
0.103049->0.00072
```

LHS is what the original timing was, RHS is the `First@AbsoluteTiming[expr]`. Note that all of these take way too long to be called as often as they are, particularly given how tiny the data was.

I think some of these calls are duplicates as the `Total` of the RHS is .067 but they're still a big time-suck.

Also note that they're mostly for resolving styling questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will need time to examine this.  No doubt plot themes are a factor here, but I think not the only factor.  How do your timings change if you use `PlotTheme -> None`?