# Create a Disk with differently colored segments automatically

Tags: graphics

How can I automatically create a `Disk` with a certain number of segments that are differently colored automatically depending on some values I input? For example, I want a disk with seven segments of a certain size, e.g. the First segment is 40 % starting and ending at some specified angle, the second one is 40 % asf. So basically I just want to input my percentages and the colors and then the disc is created. This is similar to what `PieChart` does, but I want to choose the position where a segment appears manually and it should be a graphics object.

I got as far as adjusting each of the segment in an awkwardly tedious way by manually finding the right values, but got stuck finding the right values automatically based on percentages.

```
innerDiskSize = 1
disk = {Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {0.007, Pi/1.77}], 
  Magenta, Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {Pi/1.77, 7.15 Pi/7}] , Red, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {7.15 Pi/7, 9.38 Pi/7}], Blue, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {9.38 Pi/7, 10.12 Pi/7}], Yellow, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {10.12 Pi/7, 10.95 Pi/7}], Brown, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {10.95 Pi/7, 11.85 Pi/7}] , Cyan, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, innerDiskSize, {11.85 Pi/7, 14.03 Pi/7}]   }
Graphics[disk]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this what `PieChart` does

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to choose the positions of the segments manually

Comment: `PieChart` has the option `SectorOrigin`

Comment: Yes, PieChart can do this, but it needs to be a Graphics object!

Comment: Doesn't `Head[PieChart[your input]]` return `Graphics`?

Comment: Graphics[{Head[PieChart[{4, 3, 2, 1}]]}] doesn't seem to work here :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, why `PieChart` wouldn't help you here. To create a 40%, 30%, 20%, 10% pie, just use

```
PieChart[{.4, .3, .2, .1}, SectorOrigin -> {0, 0}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The option `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` ensures that you get a pure `Graphics` without any dynamic annotations. `SectorOrigin` helps to position make your sectors start wherever you want.

If you like to colour the sectors, use the `ChartStyle` option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to embed the PieChart in a more complex Graphics object. But I figured out that I can use Inset to embed it: Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 5], 
  Inset[PieChart[{.4, .3, .2, .1}, SectorOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 11]}]

Comment: As I said, when you use `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"`, you get an ordinary `Graphics` object. So you could use for instance `pie[[1]]` to extract the graphics primitives and combine them inside another graphics without using inset.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I have at times been quite disappointed with the performance of plotting functions, e.g. [Why is ListPlot so slow here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84739/121) and I have long advocated manual `Graphics` constructs for performance, flexibility, and reliability.  Here therefore is an alternative to [`PieChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PieChart.html).

```
pie[
  v_?VectorQ,
  scheme_,
  ori : _?NumericQ : 0,
  opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]
] :=
  Module[{spec, colorfn, secfn, i = 1},

    colorfn = ColorData[{scheme, {1, Length@v}}];
    secfn = {colorfn[i++], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, #]} &;
    spec = Partition[Accumulate @ Prepend[2` Pi v/Tr[v], ori], 2, 1];

    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[0.5, Black]], secfn /@ spec, Circle[]}, opts]

  ]

pie[{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9}, "CandyColors", Pi/2]
```

[image]

And a performance comparison:

```
SeedRandom[0];
dat = RandomReal[1, 700];

pie[dat, "CandyColors", Pi/2] // RepeatedTiming // First

PieChart[dat, ChartStyle -> "CandyColors", SectorOrigin -> Pi/2, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0029
>
> 0.74
> ```

More than two orders of magnitude faster than `PieChart` despite specifying `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.  Not bad, if I do say so myself. :^)

Comment: Thank you! Very sophisticated solution ;).

Answer (score 2):

By now, I found a solution by using `Inset`in order to embed the PieChart into a Graphics object:

```
Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 7], 
  Inset[PieChart[{.4, .3, .2, .1}, SectorOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 100], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
   Automatic]}]
```

What I didn't figure out yet, is how to adjust the size of the Inset such that it has the same radius as the disk. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Use `Inset[Show[PieChart[{.4, .3, .2, .1}, SectorOrigin -> {0, 0}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], PlotRangePadding -> None], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, diameter]`

Comment: I see, thanks a bunch!