# Why PieChart Callout is so slow?

Tags: plotting

I was testing PieChart using the following random data before touching my own dataset and found the `ChartLabels` using the `Callout` function is so slow. I wonder why and is there anyway to improve its performance? I tried `PerformanceGoal→"Speed"` (learned from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153673/34223)) as the `PieChart` option, it seems to me not very effective. On my laptop, the following three `ChartLabels` option yield `0.204785, 15.0763, 48.0431` with `AbsoluteTiming`.

Generate data

```
SeedRandom[14];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 300];
stats = Counts@list
rules=Normal@stats;
```

Plot PieChart

```
Table[AbsoluteTiming[PieChart[stats, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ImageSize -> Full, opts]],
 {opts, {
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Keys@stats, "RadialCallout"], (*okay*)
   ChartLabels -> Callout[Keys@stats, Automatic], (*slow*)
   ChartLabels -> 
    Callout[Row[{Style[#[[1]], Italic], " = ", Style[#[[2]]]}] & /@ 
      rules, Automatic] (* too slow *)
   }}]
```

BTW, when I changed the `Head` to `BarChart` with the rest the same, it is faster. However, the `Callout` slow issue remained.

—————————————————————————

Further tests on my laptop showed with specific `ImageSize`, the `AbsoluteTiming` was sometimes short and sometimes long. For example. `800` or `1000` still took long execution time (> 40 sec) while `1200` and `2000` were faster (< 10 sec).

—————————————————————————

I tried the following. In general, it was faster on my laptop.

```
callout=List@@@(Normal@stats);
statsCallout=Callout[#[[2]],#[[1]]<>" = "<>ToString@#[[2]]]& /@ callout;
PieChart[statsCallout, ImageSize->1200, ChartStyle->"Pastel"]//AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: If you do: `callouts = Callout[Row[{Style[#[[1]], Italic], " = ", Style[#[[2]]]}] & /@ 
      rules, Automatic];` and then `PieChart[stats, ChartLabels->callouts]`, I think it should work fine. I imagine it's redoing the `Map` for every single label.

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks for editing the code, you lost the `ImageSize→Full` option in my original post:) But because of this, I found out the reason LoL. With `Callout` pre-calculated, the improvement of timing seems to me marginally, 47ish comparing to the original 48 with `ImageSize->Full`. But if I changed `ImageSize` to a specific size, say `2000` instead of `Full`, the timing was reduced greatly. I do not know why, but it worked.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry about that! I'm glad it inadvertently helped though.